# Need to create web application in osgi

Tags: web-applications, osgi

I have to create a dynamic web project with osgi. Referred different link available on internet but all of them are not useful. 
Please give me useful link or suggest me some way to create a web application with osgi.
I am new in osgi development so it will be helpful to get link which deals with step by step process.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, [Building Modular Cloud Apps with OSGi](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028086.do) book by Paul Bakker, Bert Ertman (O'Reilly) could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout OSGi enRoute which include tutorials: http://enroute.osgi.org/book/150-tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the OPS4j Pax Web Samples: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples
or take a look at the Apache Karaf Cookbook